# How to create JSONObject in Model Class in SpringBoot? (with value type )

Tags: json, mongodb, model, key-value

I want to create a JSONObject in model class (with value type), for example:

```
{
    _id: Number,
    status: String,
    name: String,
}
```

> The above code is for javascript, how can I do that in springboot?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? Do you want a field that stores `JSONObject` in your model class?

Comment: I want array that holds JSONObject in model class.

Comment: As per your last comment, this will suffice your requirement : 
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
 private List<JSONNode> jsonList;`
This data structure will store the data in following manner : 
`{"jsonList":[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"},{"key4":"value4"}]}`
It would be better if you share your original(like) json here.